# Golang viper cannot read configuration

Tags: go, viper

I've been trying reading configuration by viper, while it always panic nil pointer reference(i've been set the config path and config name).

Then i tried to make a execution point on it and it tells me :

> unreadable: could not read string at 0x8 due to Only part of a
> ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.

[execution point error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDEEr.png)

Here is the config directory: [Config directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7p85.png)

This is how i set the path:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqJmW.png)

I'm almost crazy of it!!! It has been bothers me for 2 days
(plz excuse me of lacking the experience of golang... I'm a new learner and thanks for your help very, very much!)

Comment: Hi, please add the error text you get here, so we can find out in which part of the code you get the error and why.

Comment: And please **do not** post images of text or links to image of text. Include the source and any output or errors directly in your question, as text, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: Please excuse me, I’m new here in stackoverflow~~ I will notice it next time and thank u for replying

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following structure:

```
|main.go
|Config
|   config.go
|   config.yaml
```

With the following lines in the file **config.go**:

```
viper.AddConfigPath(".")
viper.SetConfigName("config") // Register config file name (no extension)
viper.SetConfigType("yaml")  // Look for specific type
viper.ReadInConfig()
version := viper.Get("server.version")
fmt.Println(version)
```

And my configuration file contains:

```
server:
  version: 1.0.0
```

In this case, my version is nil.
**But**, if I set `v.AddConfigPath("./Config")`

```
viper.AddConfigPath("./Config")
viper.SetConfigName("config") // Register config file name (no extension)
viper.SetConfigType("yaml")  // Look for specific type
viper.ReadInConfig()
version := viper.Get("server.version")
fmt.Println(version)
```

Then my version is **1.0.0**.

Your path depends on where is your `main.go` and not where is your `config.go`.

If you still have problems, it could also be due to bad rights on the file. You can still try to do a `chmod 777 [your configuration file]` to check if you code didn't need more right to read the file.

Comment: I’ve tried it, but it still doesn’t work. I make an execution point at viper.New() and it tells me the viper is a nil pointer, i think the problem is that the viper isn’t initialized. While I cannot understand that I’ve used the code above in the project past and it didn’t occur any problems. But in this project it panic… crazy now